# Finding specific person in dbpedia using sparql query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

So I'm learning SPARQL and trying to get a specific person out of dbpedia using a SPARQL query. I'm using their endpoint at https://dbpedia.org/sparql to do this query. The person I'm trying to find is Albert Einstein . I found on his page that he has a property of dbp:name. So I wrote a query to find Albert Einstein by his name:

```
select ?person where {?person <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> "Albert Einstein"} LIMIT 100
```

Unfortunately, this gives me just an empty result set (I think) as i'm justing seeing an empty table with the header of 'Person'

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your query doesn't work, but this one does:

```
select ?person where {?person foaf:name "Albert Einstein"@en} LIMIT 100
```

Though this returns all entities named "Albert Einstein", which includes the scientist, but also an album of the same name. If you want just people, you can use:

```
select ?person
where {
  ?person foaf:name "Albert Einstein"@en.
  ?person a foaf:Person.
}
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: The DBpedia data is now RDF 1.1, thus, the literal is `"Albert Einstein"^^rdf:langString` . You can check this with a [DESCRIBE query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=describe+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAlbert_Einstein%3E&format=text%2Fturtle&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)

Comment: @AKSW I saw that. But why isn't it `"Albert Einstein"@en`? [The RDF 1.1. spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal) seems to imply `rdf:langString` can't be used without a language tag.

Comment: That's a good question, probably some issue with the data loaded or even something Virtuoso specific. I just looked at the [dump preview](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/preview.php?file=2016-04_sl_core-i18n_sl_en_sl_infobox_properties_mapped_en.ttl.bz2), here everything looks as it was before. Strange.